# Can I use all UPPER_CASE identifier with and without quote for different objects in the same namespace?

Tags: database, oracle, identifier

From [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements008.htm) 9th dot point:

```
Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive.
Oracle interprets them as uppercase.
Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

- part 1 -
By enclosing names in double quotation marks,
you can give the following names to different
objects in the same namespace:

employees
"employees"
"Employees"
"EMPLOYEES"

- part 2 -
Note that Oracle interprets the following names the same,
so they cannot be used for different objects in the same namespace:

employees
EMPLOYEES
"EMPLOYEES"
```

If I can give both `employees` and `"EMPLOYEES"` to different objects in the same namespace (from part 1), then why does part 2 says I cannot use `employees` and `"EMPLOYEES"` for different objects in the same namespace?

Isn't this a contradiction? Or I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the name `employees`, with no quotes, then it will be treated by Oracle as all uppercase.  In fact, `employees`, without quotes, with any letter upper/lower combination will be seen as `EMPLOYEES`.  So if you also add `"EMPLOYEES"`, then you would just be adding the same identifier.

For a more visual explanation, consider the following map:

```
input       | identifier
employees   | EMPLOYEES
EMPLOYEES   | EMPLOYEES
"EMPLOYEES" | EMPLOYEES
eMploYEeS   | EMPLOYEES
"employees" | employees
```

I would recommend not using names for your tables, columns, etc. which require escaping with double quotes.  In addition to case sensitivity issues, you should also avoid using reserved SQL keywords.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the explanation and examples you provide is very clear! In conclusion, can I say that Oracle contradicts themselves in the documentation I quoted in the question post (part 1)?

Comment: @HenryYang No, I don't see a contradiction.  But general good advice would be to use column/table names which _don't_ even require double quotes to be identified correctly.  This implies that you should not worry about case in the names.

Comment: Yes. And for the contradiction, in part 1 in my post, Oracle says you can use these 2 names in the same namespace for naming different objects [employees, "EMPLOYEES"] but in part 2 Oracle says you cannot. Do you see a contradiction now? Please correct me if you think there is something I misunderstand.

Comment: You are not understanding what is going on here.  There is no contradiction.  Part 1 says that you may name using `employees` and `"EMPLOYEES"`, but it doesn't say what happens.  Part 2 then reveals that both names would resolve to the same thing.  But now I can see where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: I see they are all valid names for object. Just for clarification, will using `employees` and `"EMPLOYEES"` as names for different objects in the same namespace cause error? Or will it cause other things to happen like updating the object definition?

Comment: It shouldn't cause an _error_ per se, but they both will refer to the same object.